# See if an object appears on camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I am making an VR Simulation that is going to be used for research purposes and I need to collect some data during the simulation. 
Such as:

- is an object being looked at (so it should be around the center of the camera)
- if it is, how long is it being looked at
- at what object is the user looking at after seeing this object.

I don't have a lot of time for trial and error and I need some pointersinto what aproach I should be using.

What scripts should I put on the object itself, what scripts should be on the camera. I don't need blocks of code (although they would help), just what I should be using and some ideas of how I should put everything together.

I'm using Oculus Rift so I know some stuff regarding the cameras might be a little different, but I think that what works for one camera should also work for the two cameras used by Oculus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of good resources for this with a simple Google search. This answer seems pretty comprehensive:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html

Answer (score 0):

Take the vector from the camera to the object `(someobject.transform.position - cam.transform.position).normalized` and dot it with the camera's `transform.forward` direction. This, depending on the positions of the camera and the object will be a value between -1 and 1. Higher value will mean the camera is looking more towards the object, so you should compare it to some threshold. If is above the threshold you set, then you win!

Comment: A very nice and clever solution, but it does not take into account occlusion. What if a big object is in front of the object we are testing for being seen? Your method would leave a false positive. Otherwise, very cool :)